# Use "remember" to store a function to cancel coroutine jobs

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, desktop-application, cancellation

How can I remember a function in Jetpack Compose? I'd like the `search` function to return another function that will cancel its two jobs so that when the user hits `search` again it won't start another parallel search but cancel the previous one:

This is the `search` function:

```kotlin
fun search(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope): () -> Unit {

        payments.clear()

        val channel = Channel<Payment>()

        val producer = coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println("Query started.")
            fetchPayments(filter, channel)
            println("Query finished.")
        }
        val consumer = coroutineScope.launch {
            updatePayments(channel, payments)
            println("Updated: ${payments.size}")
        }
        return fun() {
            producer.cancel()
            consumer.cancel()
        }
    }
```

This calls search and needs to store the cancellation function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Browser() {

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val cancelSearch = remember {} // <-- What goes in here?

    Button(onClick = { 
            cancelSearch.value() // <-- this needs to cancel the previouis search (if any)
            cancelSearch = model.search(coroutineScope) // updates the cancellation function
        }, 
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Text("Search")
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to keep function in state.

```
var cancelSearch by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<(() -> Unit)?>(null) }

Button(onClick = {
    cancelSearch?.invoke()
    cancelSearch = search(coroutineScope)
}
```

Comment: Oh, so you need the `mutableStateOf` in this case too! I'm not sure what I'm doing either ;-] I'm learning & experimenting with coroutines and I thought this might be a way to cancel the search. It works quite well! But now that I've successfully tested it... I think it might be better if I just disabled the search button so the user doesn't hit it multiple times. However, I still have another use-case that I can cancel this way (an excel export).

Comment: In fact, you can define the scopes globally here and cancel them more easily whenever you want. If you don't cancel the scopes after creating them locally, they will still function. In the event of a possible error, you may lose access to them. Anyway, it was a good question. Try and find out :))